# Split string keeping spaces in R

Tags: r, regex, string, tidyverse

I would like to prepare a table from raw text using readr::read_fwf. There is an argument col_position responsible for determining columns width which in my case could differ.
Table always includes 4 columns and is based on 4 first words from the string like besides one:
`category    variable   description      value      sth`

```
> text_for_column_width = "category    variable   description      value      sth"
> nchar("category    ")
[1] 12
> nchar("variable   ")
[1] 11
> nchar("description      ")
[1] 17
> nchar("value      ")
[1] 11
```

I want obtain 4 first words but keeping spaces to have `category`     with 8[a-b]+4[spaces] characters and finally create a vector including number of characters for each of four names c(12,11,17,11). I tried using strsplit with space split argument and then calculate existing zeros however I believe there is faster way just using proper regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution, using `stringr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

text_for_column_width = "category    variable   description      value      sth"

strings <- text_for_column_width %>% 
  str_remove("sth$") %>% 
  str_split("(?<=\\s)(?=\\S)") %>% 
  unlist

strings

#> [1] "category    "      "variable   "       "description      "
#> [4] "value      "

strings %>% str_count

#> [1] 12 11 17 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `utils::strcapture`:

```r
text_for_column_width = "category    variable   description      value      sth"
pattern <- "^(\\S+\\s+)(\\S+\\s+)(\\S+\\s+)(\\S+\\s*)"
result <- utils::strcapture(pattern, text_for_column_width, list(f1 = character(), f2 = character(), f3 = character(), f4 = character()))
nchar(as.character(as.vector(result[1,])))
## => [1] 12 11 17 11
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZXvd02/2). The `^(\S+\s+)(\S+\s+)(\S+\s+)(\S+\s*)` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S+\s+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars and then one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+\s+)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespace chars and then one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+\s+)` - Group 3: one or more non-whitespace chars and then one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+\s*)` - Group 4: one or more non-whitespace chars and then zero or more whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this pattern:

```
stringr::str_split("category    variable   description      value      sth", "\\s+") %>%
unlist() %>%
purrr::map_int(nchar)
```